# Quarterly differences

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple Spark dataframe, storing quarterly totals since the beginning of 2020.

```
|  id | year | quarter |   yq   |  total |
|:---:|:----:|:-------:|:------:|:------:|
| 1   | 2020 | 1       | 202001 | 23     |
| 1   | 2020 | 2       | 202002 | 3545   |
| 1   | 2020 | 3       | 202003 | 3      |
| 1   | 2020 | 4       | 202004 | 5345   |
| 1   | 2021 | 1       | 202101 | 3534   |
| 2   | 2020 | 1       | 202001 | 567    |
| 2   | 2020 | 2       | 202002 | 35     |
| 2   | 2020 | 3       | 202003 | 989    |
| 2   | 2020 | 4       | 202004 | 78786  |
| 2   | 2021 | 1       | 202101 | 321    |
| ... | ..   | ...     | ...    | ...    |
```

How can I compare the % difference between the current quarter and the *same* quarter from the previous year?

Expected output:

```
| id  | yq     | growth_over_same_quarter_in_previous_year |
|-----|--------|-------------------------------------------|
| 1   | 202101 | 197                                       |
| 2   | 202101 | -55                                       |
| ... | ...    | ...                                       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` to compare with the previous quarter in the same year, for the same id.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

last_year = F.lag('total').over(Window.partitionBy('id', 'quarter').orderBy('year'))

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'change',
    (F.col('total') - last_year) / last_year * 100
).filter('change is not null').select('id', 'yq', 'change')

df2.show()
+---+------+-------------------+
| id|    yq|             change|
+---+------+-------------------+
|  1|202101| 15265.217391304346|
|  2|202101|-43.386243386243386|
+---+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the filter here? To account for 0 change?

Comment: For the case if there is no previous row (e.g. yq = 202001), where `lag` will return null and so `change` will also be null @Someguywhocodes